# how to create fly out for ul li

Tags: html, css

I have an ul li structure that give me one fly out that is it gives me sub-menu but i want one more sub-menu on hover first sub-menu.

following is the structure
My Css

```
.main-navi li{
    position: relative;
}
.main-navi li div,
.main-navi a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #3a5795;
    cursor: pointer;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.main-navi li div{
    padding-left: 0;
    border: none;
}
.main-navi li div{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #1A1A1A;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #212121;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.main-navi a.active:hover,
.main-navi a.active{
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff3333;
    cursor: default;
}
.main-navi .dot{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    right: 30px;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 50%;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.main-navi li div .corner,
.main-navi a .corner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid #1A1A1A;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.main-navi li div.active .corner,
.main-navi a.active .corner{
    right: -20px;
    opacity: 1;
    border-left: 20px solid #ff3333;
}
.main-navi a.active:hover .dot,
.main-navi a.active .dot{
    background: #fff;
}
.main-navi li div:hover,
.main-navi a:hover{
    padding-left: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #151515;
}
.main-navi li div.active{
    padding-left: 50px;
    background: #ff3333;
    color: #fff;
}
.main-navi li div:hover .dot,
.main-navi a:hover .dot{
    background: #ff3333;
}
.main-navi li div.active .dot{
    background: #fff;
}
.drop-down {
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;


    position: absolute;
    top: -0;
    width: 250px;
    height:480px;
    z-index: -2;
    background: #151515;
    opacity: 0;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
  width: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
  background-color: #ff3333;
} 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button
{
  background-color: #000000;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
{
  background-color: black;
} 

.main-navi li:hover .drop-down{
    left: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
} 
.active .drop-down{
    overflow: visible;
}
.main-navi .drop-down a{
    background: #3a5795;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.main-navi .drop-down a:hover{
    padding-left: 40px;
}


<!-- code i created to get sub of sub menu-->


.drop-down-in {
    left: 100;
    overflow-y: scroll;


    position: absolute;
    top: -0;
    width: 250px;
    height:480px;
    z-index: -2;
    background: #151515;
    opacity: 1;

    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.main-navi .drop-down li:hover .drop-down-in{
    left: 200%;
    opacity: 1;
} 
.active .drop-down-in{
    overflow: visible;
}
.main-navi .drop-down .drop-down-in a{
    background: #3a5795;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.main-navi .drop-down .drop-down-in a:hover{
    padding-left: 40px;
}
<!--ends here-->
```

this is css that contains code for both sub and sub inside sub-menu. class drop-down works fine i want one more sub-menu so i created class drop-down-in which is not working.

My html code is:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home<span class="dot"></span><span class="corner"></span></a></li>
 <li><a href="about.php"> About<span class="dot"></span><span class="corner"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.php">Products And Services<span class="dot"></span><span class="corner"></span></a>
     <ul class="drop-down">
          <li><a href="calender.php">Calenders</a>
               <ul class="drop-down-in">
                    <li><a href="calender.php">Calenders</a></li>
                     <li><a href="clock_printing.php">Clock Printing</a></li>
                     <li><a href="key_chain_printing.php">key</a></li>                          
                     <li><a href="menu_cards.php">Menu Cards</a></li>
               </ul>
             </li>
             <li><a href="clock_printing.php">Clock Printing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knospe/ryk970r4/1/) to my question.

Comment: Do you know how to create fiddle ? [link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/)

Comment: sorry...?? i don't know...

Comment: add your code to fiddle

Comment: ok i will try for fiddle..

Comment: it is not working in fiddle

Comment: The Fiddle that I've added to your question contains only your code, so the others could see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the class attribute with the value "main-navi" to your first "ul" element.

```
<ul class="main-navi">
<li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home<span class="dot"></span><span class="corner"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="about.php"> About<span class="dot"></span><span class="corner"></span></a></li>
<li>
    <a href="portfolio.php">Products And Services<span class="dot"></span><span class="corner"></span></a>
    <ul class="drop-down">
        <li>
            <a href="calender.php">Calenders</a>
            <ul class="drop-down-in">
                <li><a href="calender.php">Calenders</a></li>
                <li><a href="clock_printing.php">Clock Printing</a></li>
                <li><a href="key_chain_printing.php">key</a></li>                          
                <li><a href="menu_cards.php">Menu Cards</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="clock_printing.php">Clock Printing</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And in CSS you schould update:

```
.main-navi li:hover .drop-down{
    left: 100%;
}
```

If the value for "left" is 100%, than this element wont be visible.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/knospe/ryk970r4/4/) you can find an updated Fiddle.

Comment: thank you for your fiddle work, what u have done up to their it is right, it is working fine up to that. but  drop-down-in is not working, that is drop-down-in is sub-menu from drop-down.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the Fiddle. Please check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/knospe/ryk970r4/4/

Comment: I think you are not getting what i need, see when you put mouse over on Product and services we get a menu sliding out. up to here it is right. now what i need is when you take mouse over on sub menu that is Calendrs there should be another sliding out.